# Do other animals have similar blood types to humans?

Tags: zoology, hematology

I am interested to know if there are any animals having blood groups similar to human blood groups? Is it possible to transfuse blood between humans and those animals?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [wikipedia > Blood Type (non-human)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_type_(non-human)).

Comment: One of my cats needed several blood transfusions due to low hematocrit levels, and, yes, blood typing was involved.

Comment: I have now added an answer to the 'original post' which includes some information about cats. You will see from that that if your cat is cat-type B any human blood will contain antibodies to the N-glycolylneuraminic acid on its erythrocytes and so will be rejected. I'm not sure what the situation is if your cat is cat-type A. Also I'm not sure if cat erythrocytes have one of human-H, -A or -B antigens (they are not polymorphic but they have the ABO gene), which would also have ramifications with different human blood types. Somebody must know, but I can't find it on the web.